# Can AES128-CBC encryption produce output with odd length?

Tags: encryption

I am trying to implement a SOAP client that's supposed to receive an message (XML) with MTOM/XOP attachment. The message body and attachment are encrypted using separate keys. The encryption algorithm used is AES128-CBC. The body is base64 encoded and decrypts fine, however the attachment is binary and has odd lengths (530 bytes, 527 bytes, etc).

*My question is*, is it possible that the server is messing something up in encryption? Or is it possible to produce AES128 output that's not multiple of 16?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**AES** in **CBC** mode will always produce output that is a multiple of 16 bytes.

If **AES** is used in [CTR (Counter) mode)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Counter_.28CTR.29)  it produces output with the same length as the input.

Comment: that's what I thought as well. so either the encryption isn't in CBC mode or they're not including all the bits of the encrypted message. and i have no idea who downvoted your answer, i gave you an upvote.

Answer (score 0):

AES is a block cipher and works with 16-byte blocks that is 16-bytes of data at a time. For CBC mode the input and output must be a multiple of 16-bytes. CTR mode does not have this requirement.

The way around this is to add padding bytes to the input prior to encryption and remove them after decryption. This can be done automatically by specifying a padding type, generally [PKCS#7 padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#PKCS7).